# Proper shutdown Java Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, war

I'm looking for a way to properly shutdown (Undeploy) an Java Web Application within the application itself. I've tried System.exit(), but this not only shutdown the webApp but also messes up Glassfish.

I know about the contextlistener, I'm just wondering how to start the shutdown procedure.

Comment: An application is managed by the container, and not the other way round. You're attempting to do the work of the container itself, and there's hardly going to be a portable (and secure) solution. Most likely, you'll need to use a container specific class, so long as the container allows you to invoke such a class.

Comment: Why are you trying to have an application undeploy itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to use the asadmin undeploy command.

The general form for the command is:

```
as-install/bin/asadmin undeploy war-name
```

For war-name, use the literal hello, not the full hello.war name.

For the hello.war example, the command is:

```
as-install/bin/asadmin undeploy hello
```

See the following references:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/geyvr/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1758/undeploy-1/index.html

To undeploy programmatically, you can use JSR-88 though i cant really see a reason as to why you would want to do this. See

http://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/using_jsr_88_for_web

http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=88

Comment: The Web application is in connection with local Java application by use of RMI, if by some exception the RMI connection is lost, than there is no reason for the Web application so it has to shutdown.

Comment: Use a process builder and call this to unhook yourself

Answer (score 3):

Deploying of web applications is the responsibility of application server. I do know how is it in Glassfish but other app. servers (e.g. JBoss, Tomcat etc) have web based management application that allow to do this.

If you want to undeploy application programmatically from the application itself you can use JMX. Refer to the glassfish JMX implementation to know which bean to call. But IMHO I do not think that you really need this.